# how to get the hashtable object form a class to activity in android

Tags: android, hashtable

I want to get the hashtable object from non activity class to activity class an android

please reply to me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it through the intent object using extras. Something like this

after creating the intent in your non-activity class set the value using

```
objIntent.putExtra("keyName", "somevalue");
```

In the activity class access it like this

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null)
{
String value = extras.getString("keyName");
}
```

EDIT:

```
 CityList extends Activity { 
    DBConnection server = new DBConnection(); 
    server.getDataValues(); 
    try { 
       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
       ArrayList<String> list = extras.getStringArrayList("city"); 
       System.out.println(list.get(0)); 
       System.out.println(list.get(1)); } 
    catch(Exception e) { Log.d(this.getClass(), e.getMessage()); } 
  } 

  class ServerConnection { 
    .... Intent intent = new Intent(this, CityList.class); 
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    list.add("city_1"); 
    list.add("city_2"); 
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("city", list); .. 
  }
```

Comment: i.e

class CityList extends Activity {
 DBConnection server = new DBConnection();
  server.getDataValues();
  try {
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   ArrayList<String> list = extras.getStringArrayList("city");
   System.out.println(list.get(0));
   System.out.println(list.get(1));
  } catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
}

class ServerConnection {
....
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CityList.class);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   list.add("city_1");
   list.add("city_2");
   intent.putStringArrayListExtra("city", list);
..
}

Comment: can you please edit your original post and add this as code. its not readable.